# Make field type override object generic's type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Basically what I want to happen is that the type of T(generic) be the listener's(listener field) type, that way no metter if listener is either the default value or a custom one, I'd have auto completion for "firstParatemer", is that possible? If not, is there any other way around other than setting everything to any?

Right now I can only have one type at once, either dummy or upper, not both.

Code:

```
const upper = ({ helloWorld }: { helloWorld: string }) =>
    helloWorld.toUpperCase();

const dummy = ({ worldHello }: { worldHello: string }) => worldHello;

type objType<T extends (...args: any[]) => any = typeof upper> = {
    listener?: T;
    firstParameter: Parameters<T>[0];
};

const obj: objType = {
    listener: upper,
    firstParameter: {
        helloWorld: "hello world", // auto completion
    },
};

let arr: objType[] = [
    obj,
    { listener: dummy, firstParameter: { worldHello: "world hello" } },
]; // what I want

let dummyObj: objType = {
    listener: dummy,
    firstParameter: {
        // i want auto completion here without having to specify the type with objType<typeof dummy>
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-JHSIkwXjmsCs0neClUmngWSoZARXhQAggUmEHQAN34QjJEBQwF4Awc6ZTfRTzjTBCdWWyVcGNq9dkkq3oEnoQA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want isn't directly possible, but you can create a union of the possible values instead:

```
type makeObjType<fns extends (...args: any[]) => any> = fns extends fns ? {
    listener?: fns;
    firstParameter: Parameters<fns>[0];
} : never;

type objType = makeObjType<typeof upper | typeof dummy>;
```

We use `fns extends fns` to utilize [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Then we just make the possible values with them.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0A1rW)

---

To make it work with any function, you'll have to use a helper generic function to do the inference for us:

```
function makeObj<fn extends (...args: any[]) => any>(obj: {
    listener: fn;
    firstParameter: Parameters<fn>[0];
}) {
    return obj;
}
```

and then you can use any function with it:

```
const o = makeObj({
    listener: (ok: string) => +ok,
    firstParameter: "must be string",
});
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NdYq6m)

Comment: that helps alot, is there a way to make any function work tho? with the same default behaviour being upper, but whatever function I pass it just works

Comment: @Ronkzinho The simplest way is to use a generic helper function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdYq6m). Other than that, it's really not possible to make it work with any function.

Comment: omg, exactly what I wanted, tysm, just wish there was a way to do it without functions and just create the object and setting the listener but that's fine